# struts spring hibernate maven svn

Tags: svn, hibernate, spring, maven, struts

I'm looking for a tutorial or book that explains the following technologies: Struts, Spring, Hibernate, Maven and SVN, in an example or case study under the Java EE platform.

For the database it would be nice if examples used MySQL, PostgreSQL, or Oracle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this site

http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-spring-hibernate-integration-example/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should look at [appfuse](http://appfuse.org/display/APF/Home)